# Remote Console Redirection Not Working - ASMB8-iKVM

Tags: remote-access, remote, ipmi, keyboard-video-mouse

Motherboard: ASUS Z10PE-D16/4L

Latest BIOS and BMC Firmware installed

I can browse to the management page and have full functionality with no problem.

The "snapshot" that should show the current display on the management page is blank.

When I click "Remote Control," download the jviewer.jlnp, and run it -- it seems to connect. The management page > configuration > services > ikvm shows an active session. However, the jviewer is completely black and shows "0 fps."

The management page > maintenance > BIOS post code is AE (Legacy Boot Event). While this doesn't mean that the server successfully booted the OS, it does appear that it passed POST. I've seen it cycle through other codes.

I considered it is a Java issue -- and perhaps it is -- however the BMC version I have installed was specifically created to "support Java 8 Update 181" which is the version I installed.

I am unable to ping any of the guest servers on this host, making it seem the OS isn't loading.

I am able to connect to the BMC through SSH, which brings me to a SMASH shell. Not really sure what use it is.

Any ideas?

I would be happy just being able to see/access the BIOS remotely. Any way to reset the BIOS configuration through BMC? I'm literally across the world so am not able to do anything beyond remote access.

Answer (score 2):

I have a similar Asus board (X99-WS/IPMI) board with the ASMB8-iKVM that I wanted to get this feature working also for remote management, and be able to boot from other disks.

The machine has a PCI/E Nvidia video card installed on the board, and the internal ASPEED VGA driver installed also.

The ASPEED VGA controller needs the motherboard VGA header installed to see the output from that screen, and also needs a VGA monitor attached or a VGA termination plug to keep it enabled during BIOS boot.

When Windows was loaded, I could see the ASPEED VGA controller screen, but not the screen for the Nvidia card, because the iKVM only redirects this screen, not from other video cards.
I used the Windows hotkeys to switch the ASPEED VGA as the primary screen, but when rebooting, still didn't see the BIOS screens.

To be able to view the BIOS screens also, the following changes had to be made in the BIOS settings on the board:

BOOT SECTION > ACTIVE VIDEO > ONBOARD DEVICE

BOOT SECTION > REDIRECTION SUPPORT > ENABLED

By changing the ACTIVE VIDEO setting, you will not see any BIOS output on other video cards, only from the internal ASPEED VGA controller. But you will then be able to access it remotely using the Java program.

Also make sure that the java.security file is changed to allow weaker security, was also a problem.

Hope this helps.